# Paypal - card payment

Tags: paypal

When I'm making payment through Paypal, it is working properly. But whenever I'm making a card payment, nothing is being returned in onActivityResult. I'm using Paypal SDK "PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.10.jar"

Comment: Consider adding more details. What have you tried? Can we see the code?

Comment: I have tried with this tutorial - http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/07/android-paypal-gateway-example-paypal.html

Answer (score 2):

In live, you need to check whether your account is eligible to direct credit card payments first.
Direct credit card payments is only available to UK and US. Click [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments) to view the details.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i was having same issue but it there was actually some issues in paypal sdk 2.9.10
Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 is working fine with credit card payments.
You can download the Paypal sdk version 2.9.11 from the link below.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK